# Create a share of USB drive with USBDLM

Tags: windows-7, network-shares

In Windows XP this worked (from `usbdlm.ini`):

```
[OnArrival]  
Letter=H  
open=net share H$=H:\
```

On Windows 7 I get **Access Denied** errors. How can I add users other than `Administrato`
to the group of users allowed to run the `net share` command?

The version is the latest (V4.6.9.2,) and it's installed to `C:\Program Files\usbdlm`.

Comment: What version of USBDLM are you using? Which path is it installed to?

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply. the version is the latest- V4.6.9.2, and it's installed to `c:\program files\usbdlm`